# How to write a voltage in phasor form (using a reference-voltage)

Tags: power-electronics, electromagnetism

**I have the following problem:**
Consider two voltages described by

> v<sub>1</sub> = 325 sin(wt+10º) V
> v<sub>2</sub> = 326 sin(wt+130º) V

Write v<sub>2</sub> in *Phasor Form* using v<sub>1</sub> as reference...

**My Question is:**
I understand that the angle will be 120º, but what will the voltage be?
Below is a drawing of how I am imagining it to be from a trigonometric point of view, but maybe this is the wrong way to look at the problem?

[image]

Comment: Draw a diagram and you'll see that you can work it out from trigonometry. Be careful with the angle. It's relative to V1.

Comment: @Transistor , thanks for the answer, but I am still confused on how I should go about to solve the problem, could you please give me some more guidance?:)

Comment: Draw the diagram and [edit] a sharp, cropped photo into your question. Show 0, V1, V2 and the phasor from V1 to V2.

Comment: @Transistor , hi again, I have thought a little bit more about what you said, and I have updated the question, would you mind take a look?:)

Comment: V1=325∠0 and V2=326∠120 but remember that ∠0 is used as reference for $$ \omega t +10 $$ so frequency is also important you cannot add two  voltage of different frequencies using phasors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Write v2 in Phasor Form using v1 as reference...

To find it without drawing phasors you just add/subtract \$\theta °\$ to/from **all** of your phasors where  \$\theta °\$ is the angle that when added/subtracted from your reference phasor will make it  \$0°\$.  In your case you can subtract \$10°\$ from each phasor (thus making \$v_1\$ your reference).

Making \$v_1\$ the *reference* means you adjust its angle to \$0°\$.  When you do this, the entire phasor diagram rotates with \$v_1\$ until \$v_1\$ is at the \$0°\$ position.

For example, below on the left are two arbitrary phasors \$V_X\$ and \$V_Y\$. On the right I have made \$V_X\$ the reference and put it at position \$0°\$.

[image]

What really matters with phasors is their **position relative to each other**.  Rotating the whole group around does not change their relationship to each other.  Further, you can use whatever angle you want as the reference.  Some folks use \$90°\$ so it is whatever you prefer.